# Getting data of currently signed in user in real time - Flutter & Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

- I want each user to see his/her data in real time. The app requires
     the user data to change in real time. The code I wrote is only
     showing the data of the first user in the firestore collection. When
     a second logs in, the details of the first user is shown, instead of
     the second user. Here is my code:

  ```
     _getTapCount(){   Firestore.instance.collection('user_collection').where('userId',
  ```

  isEqualTo: _uid).snapshots().listen((event) { 
         if(event.documents.isNotEmpty){
           var mydata = event.documents[0].data;
           setState(() {
             _tapCount = mydata['tapCount'];
           });
         }   }); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To become the data from the current logged in user you can use the following code as an example.

```
FirebaseUser currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
var userData = await Firestore.instance.collection("user_collection").document(currentUser.uid).get();
print(userData['userDataFieldYouWant']);
```

With the currentUser() method you become the current logged in user. After this you can become the uid from the FirebaseUser object (here currentUser) and then you can access the data from the user with the get() method.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly! How can I get the data in real time?

Comment: After the get() method you can access the data with e.g. userData['fieldName'] in your flutter code.

Comment: Yes, it is working that way.The  app requires the user data to change in real time. For example, when a button is tapped, the current user data should change in real time, without the need to refresh the page. I hope you get my point.

Comment: Okay good. When i understand you correctly i think you must first load the changed user data when the button is tapped and then you can call the setState() method in the button is tapped method. I hope this helps you.

Comment: var userData = Firestore.instance.collection('user_collection').document(currentUser.uid).snapshots().listen((event) {
  if(event.data.isNotEmpty){
    setState(() {
      _tapCount = event['tapCount'];
    });
  }
  
});